# vertically centering my text in a navbar with two divs side by side with CSS and reactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, css-position, centering

I am struggling with vertically aligning the text that is shown in the navbar below. I have one div that extends over the entire navbar as a container, and two child divs two cover each the right and left part of the navbar side by side. Centering it horizontally is no problem.

It's worth noticing that the two divs cover the navbar 50% each, so they have equal sizes.

[image: This is the navbar with its icons and one part of the text i want to display, as you can see neither the text nor the icons get displayed centered vertically. The red line in the center indicates where the navbar is splitted, since the line is drawn by hand ther could be slight inaccuracys]

I tried:

1. Working with `margin: 0 auto` this doesn't work because I need a margin of `-10` at the left to compensate the css elements of my browser (I tried working with a normalizing script but since that didn't work as expected I left it out),
2. setting `box-sizing` to `border box`,
3. translating y to `-50%`,
4. changing the positions to `relative` on the child and `absolute` on the parent,
5. Setting `top` to `50%` (doesn't work since it displaces the navbar child containers),
6. anything with `display: flex` doesn't work, because I need the two child elements to be inline blocks to fit next to each other.

Here's my code:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 2.5cm;
  margin-top: -10px;
  align-items: baseline;
  position: relative;
}

.topnav-left {
  margin-left: -10px;
  background-color: #18191C;
  height: 2cm;
  width: 50vw;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}

.topnav-right {
  background-color: #18191C;
  height: 2cm;
  width: 50vw;
  display: inline-block;
}


<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div className="wrapper">
  <div className="topnav-left">
    <Link to="/About"><u>Über</u></Link>
  </div>
  <div className="topnav-right">
    <Link to="/settings"><i class="material-icons">settings</i></Link> <!-- uses gooogle font incons -->
    <Link to="/profile"><i class="material-icons">person</i></Link> <!-- uses gooogle font incons -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there something I am missing, or perhaps a completely different idea?

Any help is appreciated

PS: there are other questions that needs help by vertically aligning text, but most of those aren't as specific on the situation;
I looked at those questions and followed little steps provided in other examples but none of these worked for me.

**Edits:**
I have added my html file for clarification of my problem so the code can be understand in a better way

```
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap');
      </style>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />

    <link rel="icon" href="Images/logo.png" /> 
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"> <!-- Use of google font icons -->  

    <title>GFOS Award</title>

  </head>
  <body style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div id="root" style="height: 100vh;" ></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: This is what happens if i use the configuration given as an answer, since i am pretty new to react and css i have not found the source of this issue]

This is what happens if i use the configuration given as an answer, since i am pretty new to react and css i have not found the source of this issue

Comment: I've converted your "App.js" to a simple sample of HTML, since that's what the browser will eventually see. Could you please correct that HTML, I'm assuming that the elements will be `<a href="/settings"><i class="material-icons>settings</i></a>`, but I don't know that for sure.

Comment: Im using a direct link i found on my google fonts account, for sure not the most performant option but it got the job done so i left it for the start of my project, i will add the html file so there is a more clear view of whtas happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why cant u use display flex?
if you just want the left div to have 50% width of the parent element, write this:

```
.topnav-left{
float: left;
width: 50%;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
}

.topnav-right{
float: right;
width: 50%;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
}
```

because you use float, you can use display: flex since the child divs dont need to be inline  blocks anymore

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best option is to work with display:flex, and I may be misunderstanding what you said you need, but I think what you are missing is to also use flex for the container too.

So you can do this:

```
.wrapper {
  width:100vw;
  height:2.5cm;
  display:flex;
}

.topnav-left {
  background-color:#18191C;
  width:50%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center
}

.topnav-right {
  background-color:#18191C;
  width:50%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:end;
}
```

Question: why the negative "margin-top" and "margin-left" in the wrapper and topnav-left respectively? If they have to do with the wrapper placement in regards to the other elements in the page, the code I gave can be adjusted to account for that. But (specially for the topnav-left) that would move the content outside of the wrapper's natural border, which would defeat the purpose of using "100vw".

Comment: the - values for the margin are since i had issues with using a normalization for the browser, if i leave it out the navbar has a margin to the left and top part of the website, this clearly can be made in a more accurate way but for now since that issue was driving me kinda crazy i wanted to do that afterwards. I know that there are resets for this like Normalize.css or the meyer reset but i had problems working with this so this was my temporary solution

Comment: A simple solution (not having to use Normalize.css for that matter) is to simply add `* { padding:0;margin:0 }` at the very top of your CSS file. (Then if you want any sort of element to have a particular margin or padding, you'd have to re-add them manually. Such as `p { margin-bottom:10px; }` or whatever...)

Comment: welp, for some reason the trick with * { padding:0;margin:0 }  didn't work i tried it and removed the other components that affect the margins but for some reason the navbar is displaced when I dont set -10 in the wrapper or the left topnav bar

Comment: In the end it did work, i just added the margin 0 and padding 0 to the wrong css file. I added it in app.css not the "real" html body

Comment: Cool! So that solves the need for those "weird" negative margins. Did you manage to place the topbars side by side as you intended? Did you try with the "display:flex" at the container?

Comment: In the end i did it, i used floats, strangely when i first tried it it didnt work, perhaps i missed something. however later on i did it again and with the floats and display: flex i was able to achieve my goal